# How to store formatted data to array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have this code to substring the array `src` into 4 characters and save each substring into `char dest[5];` array. It works fine. Now, I want to store every 4 characters into another format - unsigned int- `%u` in another array `unsigned long k[4] ;`
I've been trying to store the formatted input in k using sprintf(), but it does not giving me the conversion of each element in array dest. 
So, I could have k[0] = dest[0], k[1]= dest[1], and so on!

```
        unsigned int k [4];
        char dest[5] ; // 4 chars + terminator */
        char src [] = "123456789abcdefg"
        int len = strlen(src);
        int b = 0;
        int bb=1;
        while (b*4 < len) {
            strncpy(dest, src+(b*4), 4);

            printf("loop %s\n",dest);

           sprintf(&k, "%u",dest);
            puts(k);                
            b++;

        }
```

I just got the solution,

```
unsigned long *k = (unsigned long *) dest;
```

Anyways, Thank you guys!!

Comment: I think an nested loop could help for (i=0;i <5;i++) k [i]=dest [i];

Answer (score 1):

sprintf() and puts() expect pointer to chars, k is a pointer to unsigned int array. proper casts should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors. Here are my suggestions to fix them.

```
while (b*4 < len) {
    strncpy(dest, src+(b*4), 4);
    dest[4] = '\0';    // Make sure to null terminate dest

    printf("loop %s\n",dest);

    // Need sscanf, not sprintf
    // sprintf(&k, "%u",dest); 
    sscanf(dest, "%u", &k[b] );

    // Need printf, not puts, 
    // puts(k);
    printf("%u", k[b]);

    b++;

}
```

Comment: it is returning 0 values in every k elements.

Comment: I can see how you would get `0` in `k[3]` -- can't convert `"defg"` to a number but that shouldn't be the case for the other elements of `k`. See working code at http://ideone.com/AnZofC.